# android bluetooth connect with remote device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want connect from my app in android device to remote device (paired). remote device is a module HC-05. my cod is :

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server
            // code
            tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        ba.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        // manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
        // connected();
        tv1.setText("connect");

    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

but get error in line mSocket.connect().
when run my app then get message : unfortunately (app name) has stopped.

please help.

Comment: Did you look at error messages and exceptions in LogCat?

Comment: in this code no but in Similar code get error : read failed socket might closed or timeout read ret

Answer (score 0):

Do not silently ignore `IOException`. If you get `IOException` that means you. for any reason, could not create socket. mSocket then remains null and so you get the exception.
Might be you do not have bluetooth permission in manifest.

Comment: mSocket not null and get error : read failed socket might closed or timeout read ret